# Convert data in 10 columns into some rows

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I have a data set as following:-

```
a <- data.frame(X1="A", X2="B", X3="C", X4="D", X5="0",
                X6="0", X7="0", X8="0", X9="0", X10="0")
```

Basically it is a 1 row X 10 column data.frame.

The resulting data.frame should have the column elements of `a` as rows rather than columns. And any columns in `a` which are equal to `"0"` should not be present in the new data.frame. For ex. -

```
#          b
#     [1]  A
#     [2]  B
#     [3]  C
#     [4]  D
```

Comment: `data.frame(b=a[a!="0"])`?

Comment: I have provided an answer to you question below, if that provides a solution please check the accept answer button, if not please clarify the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a transpose and subset with a logical condition

```
 data.frame("b" = t(df1)[t(df1) != 0])
```

A second look gave me chance to play with code, you did not need a transpose

```
data.frame("b" = df1[df1 != 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `unlist` and then `subset`

```
subset(data.frame(b = unlist(a), row.names = NULL), b != 0)

#  b
#1 A
#2 B
#3 C
#4 D
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pivot_longer` function, you can reshape your dataframe into a longer format and then filter values that are "0". With the function `column_to_rownames` from `tibble` package, you can pass the first column as rownames.

Altogether, you can do something like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)


a %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Row", values_to = "b") %>%
  filter(b != "0") %>% 
  column_to_rownames("Row")

   b
X1 A
X2 B
X3 C
X4 D
```